# Did Picard violate the Prime Directive by visiting Rubicun III?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, prime-directive

The Edo were described as a pre-warp civilization. So, wasn't this  a violation of First Contact regulations?

Rimmick brings up the Edo incident in the episode Coming of Age. But his charges were just about how Picard interfered with the government, to rescue Wesley. It seems the Enterprise shouldn't  have made contact at all.